# WPA-Enterprise: is there a way to figure out the location (IP) of the RADIUS server a router is using?

Tags: networking, wpa, ieee802.1x

I'm trying to add an N router to a 802.1X network, and my router needs the IP of the RADIUS server, which I, conveniently, don't know.

Is there a way to figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd ask the tech staff. If you can, look at the settings of the other routers/APs. You could just put your N router as WPA/WPA2-PSK, if the network isn't using wired 802.1X. Sounds like you should check-in with tech staff before adding this.

- Eric Geier

Answer (score 0):

If the LAN is 802.1x protected, a consumer grade router is not going to be able to authenticate to the switch as an 802.1x supplicant. Even after that, the switch needs to be configured in multiple host mode which allows the authenticated AP to bridge its wireless clients to the LAN.

The switch should have the location of the RADIUS server, or any other AP configured the same way.